# php mail function error -> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

I am trying to send email from php to a gmail account.  I have the following settings on my laptop:

> 1. Windows 8
> 2. Internet connection
> 3. XAMPP 1.7.4, PHP Version 5.3.5,

I have the following php.ini settings

> [mail function]
>   ; For Win32 only. ; http://php.net/smtp SMTP = smtp.gmail.com ;
>   http://php.net/smtp-port
>
> smtp_port = :465
>
> ; For Win32 only. ; http://php.net/sendmail-from ;sendmail_from =
>   postmaster@localhost
>
> ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail
>   -t -i"). ; http://php.net/sendmail-path ;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

The following is the php code:

```
<?php

$to = 'goodmandiamont@gmail.com';
$subject = 'hi';
$msg = 'Test';
$headers = 'From: postmaster@localhost' ."\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: shawn.danisa@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP /' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject,$msg,$headers);

?>
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

I also made sure the IMAP setting is enabled on the gmail settings.  I also checked to see If I will find the following lines on the php.ini file:

> ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
>
> ini_set("smtp_port","465");

But no luck, I just cant find them anywhere. Please assist, I am new to php.

Answer (score -1):

Initially,  you make sure your PHP installation has SSL support (look for an "openssl" section in the output from `phpinfo()`).

Again you need to set the following settings in your PHP configuration PHP.ini

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

Hope this solves your problem.